Undefined reference to SDL_main()?
I was just trying to set things up on VS Code for C++ and SDL. I install chocolatey to install make.
I also installed all the things required.
but now this happened.
Whenever I run the command make the terminal is showing this.
g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -l mingw32 -l SDL2main -l SDL2
src/lib/libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.o): In function `main_getcmdline':
/Users/valve/release/SDL2/SDL2-2.30.3-source/foo-x86/../src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:80: undefined reference to `SDL_main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1

Here's my main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

const int WIDTH = 800 , HEIGHT = 600;
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello Red" , SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED , SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED , WIDTH , HEIGHT , SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
    if (NULL == window) {
        std::cout << "Error creating window" << SDL_GetError( ) <<  std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Event windowEvent;
    while(true) {
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
        {
            if(SDL_QUIT == windowEvent.type)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit( );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Here's my Makefile
all:
    g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -l mingw32 -l SDL2main -l SDL2

Now what should I do?

I install chocolatey to install make. You are taking a more difficult and error prone path by the steps you have done. My advice is to remove all of the SDL, MinGW and everything you installed via chocolatey for this. Instead follow the official VSCode instructions and use msys2 to install MinGW + SDL using the pacman package management in msys2. The official VSCode instructions for MInGW are here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Your code looks fine, it should work. Where did you install SDL2 from? Are you sure this is the exact code and makefile you're using?

Then please create an answer to share you insights. Even "using the official guide helped" would be helping with convincing the armies of new users who inspite of being new not only use the newbie-unfriendly VSC but on top of that choose to do it in an even more risky way. This is not meant sarcastic, your experience would really help.

Wrong libraries order I guess? -lSDL2 -lSDL2main; first one that needs the symbol, then one that provides it

@AndreyTurkin SDL_main is not provided by either of those libraries, it's provided by OP's code because of #define main SDL_main.

Yeah, I figured that out a bit later. Apparently for some reason this define doesn't get set up (though I tried the same in mingw64 and everything worked just fine).
